# Devolver un vector

Tags: c++

necesitaría ayuda para terminar este ejercicio, no sé si guarda en el vector los números primos, y como lo podría imprimir, gracias.
Enunciado: 
Desarrollar una función que devuelva en un vector los números primos entre 2 y200

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void numeros_primos() {
    int num, i, contador;
    bool es_primo;
    int pos = 0;
    int vector_primos[200];
    for(num = 2; num < 201; num++){
        contador = 2;
        es_primo = true;
        while (es_primo == true && contador < num){
            if (num % contador != 0) {
                contador += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                es_primo = false;
            }
        }
        if (es_primo = true){
            vector_primos[pos] = num;
            pos += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    numeros_primos();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero, tienes un error de lógica en cuanto al concepto de primo. Ten en cuenta que un número **es primo si solo  es divisible entre el mismo y la unidad**. Por lo tanto, lo que debes comprobar es si entre 2 y `n - 1` hay algún número que sea divisor de `n`, en el momento que exista **uno solo** el número no es primo.

`contador` debe incrementarse en cada iteración del `while` ya que es el divisor a probar, si alguno da como resto 0 entonces debes romper el ciclo porque ese número ya no es primo. Si el ciclo se completa, entonces el número es primo.

Por otro lado tu array se crea en la función y de ella no sale. En cualquier caso, en C++ moderno el uso de arrays crudos está desaconsejado en favor de los contenedores de la biblioteca estándar, puedes usar `std::vector`, a partir de  C++ 11 puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<int> numeros_primos(void) {
    int num, contador;
    bool es_primo;
    std::vector<int> vector_primos;

    for(num = 2; num < 201; num++){
        contador = 2;
        es_primo = true;
        while (~es_primo && contador < num){
            if (num % contador == 0) {
                es_primo = false;
            }
            contador++;
        }
        if (es_primo){
            vector_primos.push_back(num);
        }
    }
    return vector_primos;
}


int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> primos = numeros_primos();
    for(auto const& primo: primos){
        std::cout << primo << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No obstante, hay algunas optimizaciones que se pueden hacer en el algoritmo:

- No tienes que comprobar los números pares, menos el 2 todos son compuestos.
- Como todos los factores son impares o 2, solo tienes que probar éstos como divisores.
- No hay que comprobar desde 2 hasta `n - 1`, basta con hacerlo hasta la raíz cuadrada de `n`. Siempre se cumple que al menos un factor es menor a la raíz cuadrada del número compuesto.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


std::vector<int> numeros_primos(void) {
    int num, div;
    bool es_primo;
    std::vector<int> vector_primos;

    vector_primos.push_back(2);
    for(num = 3; num < 200; num += 2){
        es_primo = true;
        for(div = 3; div <= std::sqrt(num); div += 2){
            if (num % div == 0) {
                es_primo = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (es_primo){
            vector_primos.push_back(num);
        }
    }
    return vector_primos;
}


int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> primos = numeros_primos();
    for(auto const& primo: primos){
        std::cout << primo << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```